# When npm install/ci honors package-lock.json, is there any purpose of using tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json, npm-ci

In case an application has a package-lock.json or shripkwrap.json, both npm install/npm ci command would honor the dependencies versions (in package-lock.json or shripkwrap.json), what purpose would tilde(~) and caret(^) serve in package.json?

Comment: npm allows installing newer version of a package than the one specified. Using tilde ( ~ ) gives you bug fix releases and caret ( ^ ) gives you backwards-compatible new functionality as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

Tilde `~` and caret `^` are used in *package.json* to say that your software is compatible with new patch or minor versions of a specific dependency.

But as you've identified, `npm install` ignores new patch or minor versions when a *package-lock.json* file is present.

Instead, run `npm update`.

This installs the latest version of any dependencies, based on how you've defined the version in *package.json*. It also updates *package-lock.json* accordingly.